# What size wire should I use when building a chandelier?

Tags: wiring

I'm attempting to build 4 mason jar chandeliers for my daughter's wedding. Each chandelier will have 17 jars with bulbs.

What size wire should I use to wire the chandelier?

Most evidence I've found says 18 gauge but I will be using an eleven watt bulb. Will the lower wattage bulb make a difference in the wire?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Be awfully careful building those chandeliers; your daughter may never forgive you if you electrocute a few of her friends.

Comment: What are you making these chandeliers from?

Comment: If you post a sketch of your design, folks may also have suggestions for things like mechanical strength, ease of wiring (where are these wires getting spliced together?) and the like.

Answer (score 1):

18 gauge wire is the smallest wire allowed by the NEC for wiring within a fixture or luminaire:

> **402.6 Minimum Size.** Fixture wires shall not be smaller than 18 AWG.